# $ is not a function. Backbone, jQuery and Browserify

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, backbone.js, browserify

I am creating node app with browserify to modularize frontend code.
Unfortunately, I can't get Backbone working, because it's throw this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object #<Object> is not a function
```

jQuery is loaded before this script:

```
var _ = require('underscore'),
    Backbone = require('backbone');

// Here, jQuery works fine.
$(function() {
  Backbone.history.start();
});
```

It's seem like Backbone couldn't find jQuery when using browserify.

Comment: you probably need a shim for backbone, do you have a config somewhere?

Comment: What do you mean by "config"? Backbone should works with CommonJS modules so it doesn't need shim.

Comment: is $ undefined when you put a breakpoint at the line that causes the error?

Comment: http://cl.ly/text/1P0V0I1v3j3B- here's fragment of code where error is performing.

Comment: Yes, sorry. I have updated link.

Comment: Can you see jQuery in your sources?

Comment: What version of Backbone are you using?

Comment: jQuery is loaded from separate file (I have tried loading using browserify, but I got same error). I can use jQuery from Developer Console. I am using Backbone 1.1.0.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just set `Backbone.$ = window.$` manually. Backbone looks for jquery in a global variable (which is  defined by capturing `this`) and it's likely that browserify runs script not in a global context (which is consistent with CommonJS).

Comment: It worked, but why I need to do that? jQuery is in global variable because it's loaded from another file.

Comment: I think something like this happens: http://jsfiddle.net/zw4Pc/1/ , that is, browserify wraps modules in functions and calls it on some other context, like module context. If Backbone used `window.$` reference it workered, but Backbone uses `this.$` to capture jQuery.