# How to use browserify to bundle a backbone app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, backbone.js, browserify

I'm running into a little trouble with browserify.

### The Goal

I'm trying to build the basic TodoMVC single-page app with Backbone, only instead of heaps of `<script>` tags in my `index.html`, I'm trying to bundle them all up with browserify.

Here's what I have going so far.

**lib/models/todo.js**

```js
var backbone = require("backbone");

var Todo = module.exports = backbone.Model.extend({

  defaults: function() {
    return {
      title: "",
      completed: false,
      createdAt: Date.now(),
    };
  },

});
```

**lib/collections/todo.js**

```js
var backbone     = require("backbone"),
    LocalStorage = require("backbone.localstorage");

var TodoCollection = module.exports = backbone.Collection.extend({

  localStorage: new LocalStorage('todomvc'),

});
```

**lib/app.js**

```js
var Todo            = require("./models/todo"),
    TodoCollection  = require("./collections/todo");

(function(global) {

  global.todoCollection = new TodoCollection([], {model: Todo});

})(window);
```

To build my bundle, I'm using

```sh
browserify lib/app.js > js/app.js
```

Lastly, my `index.html` is quite simple

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Todo MVC</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

### The Problem

When I open the console and try to run this command

```js
todoCollection.create({title: "My first todo"});
```

I get an error

> "Cannot read property 'Deferred' of undefined"

Stacktrace

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'Deferred' of undefined
    at Backbone.LocalStorage.sync.window.Store.sync.Backbone.localSync (http://localhost:4000/js/app.js:182:47)
    at Backbone.sync (http://localhost:4000/js/app.js:255:40)
    at _.extend.sync (http://localhost:4000/js/app.js:1773:28)
    at _.extend.save (http://localhost:4000/js/app.js:1979:18)
    at _.extend.create (http://localhost:4000/js/app.js:2370:13)
    at <anonymous>:2:16
    at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateOn (<anonymous>:580:39)
    at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateAndWrap (<anonymous>:539:52)
    at Object.InjectedScript.evaluate (<anonymous>:458:21)
```

### The Question

I've done quite a bit of searching on how to browserify backbone apps, but I've found little in terms of things that match my objective.

How can I bundle my single-page backbone app into a single `app.js` that I can require in the html?

**As an aside**

I'm not sure if I'm including jQuery properly either. Is Backbone going to have trouble connecting itself to jQuery if it's also not part of my browserified bundle?

Any tips are greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is the same issue as here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19528559/is-not-a-function-backbone-jquery-and-browserify/19529354#19529354

Comment: @vkurchatkin, I'm not sure it is. My error has nothing to do with jQuery and none of my Backbone code is dealing w/ the DOM yet. That said, I could be wrong...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Edit:**

The most recent version of jquery is distributed and usable via npm! This makes using jquery with browserify simpler.

All we need to do now is install the packages:

```
npm install jquery backbone
```

And require the modules:

```
var $ = require('jquery');
var Backbone = require('backbone');
Backbone.$ = $;
```

**Old answer:**

I've used the [jquery-browserify](https://npmjs.org/package/jquery-browserify) module successfully for this.

Run `npm install jquery-browserify backbone`

Creating a view module in a file named app-view.js:

```
var Backbone = require('backbone');
var $ = require('jquery-browserify');
Backbone.$ = $;

module.exports = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize: function(){
    this.render();
  },

  render: function(){
    console.log('wuuut')
    $('body').prepend('<p>wooooooooooooooo</p>');
  }
});
```

Using the module:

```
var AppView = require('./app-view')

var appView = new AppView();
```

You can keep jquery in a script tag like in your code rather than using jquery-browserify, but in that case instead of this:

```
var $ = require('jquery-browserify');
Backbone.$ = $;
```

I would do this:

```
var $ = Backbone.$ = window.$;
```

Comment: You should be able to fix this using browserify-shim as well:      "browserify-shim": {
        "jquery": "$",
        "log4js": "Log4js",
        "underscore": "_",
        "backbone": {
          "exports": "Backbone",
          "depends": [
            "jquery:$",
            "underscore:underscore"
          ]
        }

Answer (score 3):

Since jQuery v2, it is capable of exposing itself as `module.exports`. That is, you can install the `jquery` module instead of something like `jquery-browserify`.

```
npm install jquery backbone
```

But it is still necessary to correct Backbones `$` property manually.

```
var backbone = require('backbone')
backbone.$ = require('jquery')
```

Answer (score 2):

It is a 100% percent jQuery issue. The error is: Cannot read property 'Deferred' of undefined. Where Deferred is supposed to be? In jQuery (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Deferred/). Here it is a specific line, that causes an error: https://github.com/jeromegn/Backbone.localStorage/blob/master/backbone.localStorage.js#L145.
Just do `Backbone.$ = window.$` when you require backbone for the first time and it will work.