# Browserify Cannot find module when trying to bundle many js files

Tags: node.js, ssh, browserify

This is my first day doing node, I'm having some problems trying to bundle some js files.

```
MyFolder
|-- app (folder)   
|  |-- Collections (contains: movies.js)   
|  |-- Models (contains: movie.js)  
|  |-- node_modules  
|-- main.js  
|-- node_modules (folder)    
|-- static (folder)
```

This is the content of js files I want to compress into static/bundle.js.

```
 // app/models/movie.js  
 var Backbone = require("backbone");
 var Movie = Backbone.Model.extend({
   defaults: {
     title: "default",
     year: 0,
     description: "empty",
     selected: false
   }
 });
 module.exports = Movie;

 // app/collections/movies.js  
 var Backbone = require("backbone");
 var Movie = require('models/movie');
 var Movies = Backbone.Collection.extend({
      model: Movie
 });
 module.exports = Movies;
```

When I run `browserify -r ./app/main:app > static/bundle.js` the file bundle.js is created with the scripts from app/main.js. It works as expected.

But when I run `browserify -r ./app/collections/movies.js:movies \ -r ./app/models/movie.js:movie > static/bundle.js`, it creates an empty bundle.js and shows this:

```
Error: Cannot find module '/Users/MyFolder/app/models/movie.js:movie' from '/Users/MyFolder'
```

My folder `app/node_modules` is sync with `ln -sf ../models .` and `ln -sf ../collections .`

**Question 1:** Any hint what I'm doing wrong?
**Question 2:** If `static/bundle.js` exists. Does running browserify again overwrites the file or not? On my local tests it doesn't overwrite, so am I supposed to delete this file each time for update?

Answer (score 28):

Might consider adding `./` to your path:

```
var Movie = require('./models/movie');
```

see: [How to use browserify to bundle a backbone app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19747500/how-to-use-browserify-to-bundle-a-backbone-app?rq=1)

Comment: Yep! that solved my problem, I used Bable to convert my ES6 program and I thought it will do that

Comment: Spending half an hour through the web to finally find the correct answer to my issue... Real thanks mate.

Answer (score 9):

For people coming from search engines:

It might be that you are using a mac and you have not used proper case while requiring the file.

This is equivalent in mac:

```
require('./someFile');
require('./somefile');
```

But not in centOs for example.

Comment: Thank you for this. This is why importing a package with a wrong capital letter was working on my OS X dev machine but not on my Linux server.

Answer (score 1):

If you use your debugger and step into the `require` call you'll find yourself inside some minified code (typically).

```
(function e(t,n,r){function s(o,u){if(!n[o]){if(!t[o]){var a=typeof require== ...
```

Go to your console and inspect `t[o][1]`

This will show you a list of the correct paths for your modules.

```
Object {
    '<module name>' : <id>
    ...
}
```

If this becomes too confusing temporarily un-minify the first line in your compiled `bundle.js` file (I use `alt-cmd-l` in PhpStorm) and try again.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. In my case, it's because Browserify does not detect the file if it's not directly specified in the require.

Example:

Change:

```
var f = 'filename'
var handler = require('./' + f + '.js'); --> this will generate an error
```

To:

```
var handler = require('./filename.js');
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same error recently. I am running Browserify using Gulp 4.

The problem was that I was reorganizing my project folder architecture and I did not empty the destination (`dist`) folder for my bundled `.js` files. After I emptied that folder (in my case it was called `assets`) and run Browserfy it was working fine again.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I replaced

```
const router = require(path.join(__dirname, 'router'))
```

to

```
const router = require('./router')
```

for it to work. It seems Browserify does not support local file access through node 'path' module