# Browserify - cannot find module 'jquery'

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, npm, browserify

I am trying to bundle up my app with browserify and am getting this error:
 `Cannot find module 'jquery' from '/home/test/node_modules/backbone'`

Now questions of this nature have been asked before, but the solutions haven't helped me. Perhaps I have somewhat of a unique case.

In another app, running `npm install jquery` fixed it. I didn't have it in my `package.json` and I wasn't requiring `jquery` in any of my files like what's done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19747500/how-to-use-browserify-to-bundle-a-backbone-app). Everything worked.

In this new app, it doesn't. I tried reinstalling jquery with npm. Nothing. Added it to my dependencies in `package.json`. Nothing. Included it in my code:

`$ = require('jquery'); Backbone.$ = $;`

Nothing.

Does anyone have experience with this? What could be going wrong?

**Edit:**

Diff'd the `package.json` of the jquery module in the working app and the current one.

Working one:

```
 "url": "https://github.com/jquery/jquery.git"
 "_from": "jquery@*"
```

Broken one:

```
 "url": "git+https://github.com/jquery/jquery.git"
 "_from": "jquery@>=2.1.0 <3.0.0"
 "readme": "ERROR: No README data found!"
```

If you want more context (line numbers, parent property, and such), I'd be happy to provide that. I just wanted to simplify it - maybe something stands out.

**Edit 2:**

Changing the `"url"` param shouldn't changed anything. Replacing the `"_from"` with the one that works didn't change anything.

Now, I'm wondering why `README data` is not found. My README files are the same. Granted, I highly doubt that this is the source of the problem.

**Edit 3:**
My solution was to remove the jquery module and just include jquery.js in my index view. I'm not particularly happy with this, but it works.

I would still like an answer though; curious what was wrong before.

Comment: I ran into the same error when I was using `npm link` to symlink a dependency that I was developing outside of npm. Sounds different than your situation though.

Comment: I ran into this too... Was your symlink dependency requiring Backbone which was requiring jQuery?  `npm install jquery` from the symlink dep fixed the problem... but I would also setup the browserify shim in the dep folder rather than the parent proejct.

Comment: @ilovett Thanks for your help. Unfortunately this was a project I was working on during the summer and don't have access to my code anymore. I don't understand what exactly a symlink dependency is, but Backbone (or its Views at least) do require JQuery.

Comment: @Pushkin Backbone requires jQuery for ajax calls as well.

Comment: http://rkulla.blogspot.com/2014/04/using-browserify-with-jquery-backbonejs.html

Answer (score 2):

This should work well with `npm install --save jquery`. Seems that `browserify` searches for `jquery` module in `backbone` location. Can you find out why is this so ? Don't you have some `browserify-shim` configuration errors in your `package.json` ?

If you still have problem you can use `browserify-shim` to point `browserify` to proper location by putting this in `package.json`

```
  "browserify": {
    "transform": [
      "browserify-shim"
    ]
  },
  "browser": {
    "jquery": "./node_modules/yet/old/jquery/location"
  }
```

Comment: I am no longer working on this project, so I cannot answer your questions nor test your solution. Thanks anyway