# Error while using browserify with backbone and jquery

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, browserify

This is what I have written:

```
var underscore = require('underscore');
var $ = require('jquery')(window);
var Backbone = require('backbone');
Backbone.$ = $;
```

And then executed this command `browserify app.js -o bundle.js`

When I run the application, I get the following error in chrome console:

app code:

```
//Define The Model

    $(function () {
        var Shape = Backbone.Model.extend({
            defaults: {x: 40, y: 40, width: 100, height: 100, color: 'brown'},
            setTopLeft: function (x, y) {
                this.set({x: x, y: y});
            },
            setDim: function (w, h) {
                this.set({width: w, height: h});
            },
            isCircle: function () {
                return !!this.get('circle');
            }
        });
      });
```

**Error:** Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: I think the second line should be `var $ = require('jquery');` without `(window)`

Answer (score 0):

Not being 100% sure but I think this is a shim problem, you're not exposing correctly $ to your app

Comment: Can you be more clear? I didn't understand what you said

Comment: I'm saying Backbone has no .$ property =/

Comment: Did you see this `Backbone.$ = $;`?

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19747500/how-to-use-browserify-to-bundle-a-backbone-app?rq=1

Comment: What re you trying to do ? by the way what is triggering the error exactly ? when you run the app

Comment: Are you using webpack ?

Comment: I am using broswerify. Its similar to webpack

Comment: Updated the question. The first line(anonymous function) is causing the error

Comment: also I'm curious to know what are trying to do wrapping your model in a jquery callback ?

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is remove `(window)` in the require jquery:

```
var $ = require('jquery');
```

Essentially, with `var $ = require('jquery')(window)` you are creating a jquery object which contains the `window` object. It is the same as if you were doing something like this: `var $win = $(window)`. Then the `$win` variable would be the window global object wrapped with jquery, something that is actually useful in certain scenarios.

*Credit goes to Spike for noticing the mistake first in the comment, but I have tested it and posting this as an answer.*

Comment: I removed (window) as suggested, but still the same error `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined`